# Cannot find getValue in firebase

Tags: java, firebase

I have a firebase repository, and the data is structured like the following:

[image]

I am writing java code and i just want to get the value of "listname". HEre is what i do:

```
Firebase f = new Firebase("https://marketlist.firebaseio.com/sharedlists/list1/listname");
```

and then, when i look at member functions of my firebase object f, isee that there is a getName() function that returns listname, which is "list1", but there is no getValue() function here. Also, i tried

```
Query q = f.startAt("list1").endAt("list1");
```

but again, i cannot get the value. Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase's logic is that data may change over time. So instead of exposing a value on the Firebase reference, you need to **listen** for changes like this:

```
f.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var val = snapshot.val();
});
```

Inside this callback function, `val` will now have `list1` as its value.

If/when the value of `listname` changes, the callback will be called again and `val` will have the new value.

**Update**

I had missed that you use Java, so the above example is for JavaScript.

In Java the mechanism is very similar, but syntactically different:

```
f.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    String val = (String) snapshot.getValue());
  }

  @Override public void onCancelled() { }
});
```

So you attach a listener through `addValueEventListener`. Then the `onDataChange` method is invoked immediately for the initial value and whenever the referenced value changes.

Comment: Thanks, but i think you are giving an example of javascript code. I am writing in java and there is no on function there

Comment: also, what if data does not change? In that case listener will not be triggered, and so how can i get the value?

Comment: You will always get an initial value when you declare the listener.

Comment: Oh thanks, i thought onDataChange will only be triggered when there is a data change, but actually it is first triggered when the listener is  created.

Comment: @Kato That was exactly what I was looking for. The fact that it initializes when you declare listener is not obvious from the official docs. Very difficult to find that as an answer anywhere.

Comment: From the [Firebase documentation on value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events): "[The onDataChange method] is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes."